# Defining an OLAP cube with dynamic measures and dimensions

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I am using SSAS 2012 to define an OLAP cube. For the most part this is going fine. However, there's one area where I'm stumped: Metadata.

### What?

We have a multi-tenant system where we allow tenants to augment their fact data with arbitrary metadata. A tenant can predefine a number of metadata fields (e.g. `Author` and `Color`). Then, every fact can have a value associated for zero or more of these fields (e.g. Fact #47 has Author `Bob` and Color `Yellow`). These are stored in our database in a regular relational way in two separate `metadata fields` and `metadata values` tables.

I would like to be able to use these fields both as dimensions (e.g. aggregate based on `Color`) but also as measures (e.g. `# of Colors` for every `Author`).

### How?

As a MDX newbie there two approaches I can think of:

1. Dynamically add these dimensions and measures, but due to our multi-tenant approach I'd probably have to
2. Have some form of dynamic dimension and dynamic measures.

Are there any better approaches? If not, how would the second option be implemented?

An additional note: Tenants don't directly access the cube, we have an API in-between. So this does not need to work in PowerPivot or anything.

Comment: As you have your own API, you could also just add the things the users add dynamically in your query in a `WITH` clause. Another possibility would be giving write access to the cube to the users (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174540.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg567303.aspx). And, finally, you could have the dimension writing going to the relational tables and the measures changing the cube definition. Which possibility would be best depends a lot on the complexity of the cube structure, requirements on user editable calculations, etc.

Comment: have you considered creating a sort of junk dimension that is just a description and value.  So description = 'Color', value = 'Yellow'; Description = 'Author', Value = 'Bob'. This would work for your requirement of being used as both a dimension and fact.  It might cause a M:M relationship with other tables to which it is related.

Comment: @mmarie: When defining this junk dimension: How would I define a measure based on, say, distinct count of different values for "Color", though?

Comment: @RoyJacobs You use the same table to create a measure group. Create a measure that is just count, to count the number of rows.  Also create a distinct count measure.  Then when you slice by description and value, you can see all the rows that are color and yellow. And if you slice just on description of color, you can see the count of distinct values with the second measure.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm clearly not up to speed on MDX yet, but this is a good starting point :)